# Loadbalancer for multiple web applications on single EC2 cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elb, amazon-vpc

This may seem an obvious for people who have worked with AWS but I have a lot of trouble figuring out on how to set up a loadbalancer on 2 EC2 instances which are hosting multiple websites.

We have 2 Windows 2012 R2 machines set up, I have created one ELB and from what I have read, I know you can point that ELB to one location (assuming its the default site on the servers). How would I go about pointing say other ELBs that I create to point to the other applications on the server? (Not sure if this info is relevant but just to add : This whole setup is a part of VPC, Domain Controller environment and the web servers are in public subnet. )

Comment: Could you please provide more details on the architecture like how your web, app servers, ELBs and subnets are laid out?

Comment: Sure. We have VPC and inside of VPC we have 2 subnets. Private subnets have all the SQL servers, Domain Controller, App Servers, Search Servers. In Public subnet we have just the public facing web servers. private subnet connects to internet using NAT. Each public facing site has EIP. One of such servers has 4 asp.net applications (2 servers actually). I need a load balancer so that I can check the health of all the applications on those 2 VMs. if this description doesn't help, I can give a pictorial representation. Let me know if that description helped at all.

Comment: do the apps run on separate ports?

Comment: No all of them are on port 80.

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this is by running your applications in multiple IIS websites.

Each of the websites should have a different [site binding](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731692(v=ws.10).aspx) with a different host name. You could use the DNS name of the load balancer for each website.

Alternatively you can use a domain name configured in [Route53](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-values-alias.html) and use an A record to point to the load balancer.